# Atom editor, abrir script php no localhost (Testar no browse)

Tags: php, localhost, atom

No Netbeans ao clicar no |> (play) eu executo o meu projeto php no localhost.
Agora estou testando o editor Atom e queria saber se existe algum plugin / extensão que habilite essa função.
Abrir no browse arquivos html, já consegui, mas executar o "index.php" não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Acredito que não... Mas tu podes usar o WAMP Server e abrir sempre teus arquivos PHP: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Obrigado @ThiagoSantos mas está tudo funcionando no Netbeans, eu apenas queria testar o Atom Editor.
Inclusive já instalei esse package "https://atom.io/packages/open-in-browser"  e funciona com arquivos HTML, mas quando precisa executar o script PHP no localhost, esse não é útil.

Answer (score 1):

Carlos, você consegue abrir o HTML pois é interpretado por qualquer Browser. Porém o PHP é necessário que você instale um servidor PHP.
Antigamente o que normalmente era instalado era o apache2, porém hoje com o PHP 7 você pode executar o comando pelo CMD ou terminal:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t seudiretorio/index.php
```

Provavelmente o NetBeans deve ter algum servidor PHP embutido, por isso o mesmo funciona.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Vale acrescentar que o atom tem um plugin de terminal: https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus

Comment: @Nataniel Paiva / JuniorNunes  Talvez eu tenha me expressado mal ao formular a pergunta, mas o meu sistema está funcionando bem no localhost, e também no servidor on line na web, Não tem nenhum servidor embutido no Netbeans, então não é esse problema e sim apenas acrescentar o recurso de executar o projeto (no editor Atom), que nativamente já tem no netbeans.
Vou testar o plugin indicado.